# Rate Limiting with Flow in Elixir

Tags: elixir, genstage

As part of a data flow, I'd like to download a list of files at 10 request / second.
[image]

Is sleeping the thread as [as done here](https://10consulting.com/2017/01/20/building-product-recommendations-using-elixir-gen-stage-flow/) the best approach?

```
case ExRated.check_rate(@endpoint, scale, limit) do
  {:ok, _} ->
    request.()

  {:error, _} ->
    :timer.sleep(1_000)
    rate_limit_access(request, opts)
end
```

Is it possible to do something like what's done with `gen_stage` [here](https://github.com/elixir-lang/gen_stage/blob/master/examples/rate_limiter.exs), or what's the best approach to rate limit sections using `Flow`?

Comment: The question is a bit unclear, but in general back pressure issues are usually to be solved with [`GenStage`](https://hexdocs.pm/gen_stage/GenStage.html) and [`GenStage.DemandDispatcher`](https://hexdocs.pm/gen_stage/GenStage.DemandDispatcher.html#content). `Process.sleep/1` is _never_ a good approach.

Comment: Basically I want to ensure that if I have N processes downloading, I cumulatively don't exceed X requests per second. I've seen this [rate limiter](https://github.com/elixir-lang/gen_stage/blob/master/examples/rate_limiter.exs) example, but I'm not sure how I'd integrate that with flow.